# How can I correctly convert binary characters in list to decimal

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to create a function which will convert the binary numbers in list array to the decimal numbers. For that I have reversed a list and used for loop to iterate the list items. However I am unable to get correct result. Can anyone help me where am I committing the mistake?

```py
def binary_array_to_number(arr):
     #arr = arr.reverse()
    arr = arr [::-1] 
    new_num = 0
    for item in arr:
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            new_num = new_num+item*(2**i)
    print(new_num)
binary_array_to_number(arr= [0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what output are you getting?

Comment: I expect to get 1 for [0,0,0,1] but instead I am getting 15

Comment: still the answer is 15 only. I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the current bit is `1` or not, so you'll always generate `2**n - 1`. Also, you've got two loops running instead of one, which will also lead to an incorrect result.

```py
def binary_array_to_number(arr):
     #arr = arr.reverse()
    arr = arr [::-1] 
    new_num = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i]:
            new_num += (2**i)
    print(new_num)
binary_array_to_number(arr= [0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @AnilAwasthi edited the answer to fix an issue

Comment: so if arr[i] basically checks whether the bit is 1 or not, right? Can you elaborate on this please, I am new to python programming. So I have difficulty grasping even the simple concepts

Comment: `if arr[i]` basically checks if `arr[i]` isn't `0` or `None`

Comment: so if arr[i] will check whether the array is empty or not after each iteration, right

Comment: No, it checks if the i-th element is 1 or not

Comment: oh, Now I got it. Thank you so much for clarifying

Comment: Consider upvoting and marking it as the accepted answer if it solves your purpose

Comment: sure. I will do it. This is my first question I have ever asked on stack overflow. Hence I am slowly getting the hang of it

Comment: I am an absolute beginner to python. Do you have any tips or roadmap on how I can speed up my learning process? I will appreciate any suggestions and will be valuable for me.

Comment: Pickup simple projects, start something like 100 Days Of Python, read docs. That's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in conversion from binary to base-10 numbers using the `int()` constructor. By converting the array to a string representing the binary number, you can use `int` to convert it to decimal:

```py
binary_arr = [0, 0, 0, 1]
binary_string = ''.join(str(digit) for digit in binary_arr)  # this line simply converts the array to a string representing the binary number [0, 0, 0, 1] -> '0001'
decimal_number = int(binary_string, 2)  # the 2 here represents the base for the number - base 2 means binary.
print(decimal_number)  # prints '1'
```

Comment: Doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: OP's question is how to convert a binary list to a decimal number. This code does that.

Comment: "Can anyone help me where am I committing the mistake?" is what the question body reads

Comment: Well, the whole issue would be avoidable using python's built in conversion. I'm still answering the question.

Comment: You are also correct. But being an absolute beginner, I don't know how to use built in conversions like these. Do you have any tips on how can I speed up learning python

Comment: Asking questions about things like these is a good way to learn neat tricks that otherwise might have gone undetected. There are many great tutorials out there, but nothing covers every aspect of the language.